# Why does curl require both .lib and .dll to work?

Tags: c, dll, curl

I just downloaded [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and managed to build a programe with it.

What I don't understand is why it requires both `curllib.lib` and `curllib.dll` ?

In my opinion either `curllib.lib` or `curllib.dll` should be enough, why both?

Also I've searched through the source but doesn't find anywhere it uses `dlopen` to load `curllib.dll`, so why is `curllib.dll` required to run?

Comment: Difference between dll and lib is as follows:
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-lib-and-dll/

Answer (score 3):

`curllib.lib` is the import library. It contains stubs for all the functions whose actual code is in the DLL, and it contains code to load the DLL. The `.lib` is automatically generated by the build system (e.g. Visual Studio), which is why you won't find any references in the code. You will find, however, some directives that tell the compiler/linker to export certain functions:

- `__declspec(dllexport)` on a function declaration will export that function. This is convenient, but Microsoft-specific. For example:

  `void __declspec(dllexport) foobar(int qux);`

  [More information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28VS.80%29.aspx).
- Alternatively, a `.def` file can be used, that explicitly lists all functions that are exported. For example:

  `LIBRARY MYFOO`
  `EXPORTS`
  `foobar @1`

  [More information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28VS.80%29.aspx).

You can do without the `.lib` if you really want to, but you'll have to manually use `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and friends to call the function in the DLL.

Comment: Can you list a few `directives that tell the compiler/linker to export certain functions` ?

Comment: Will the exported `dll` be automatically named according to the `lib`? Say the dll for `curllib.lib` will be `curllib.dll`? I ask this because I don't find any explicit reference to `curllib.dll` in the possible derectives..

Comment: The name will be the same. By default, Visual C++ will give both the `.lib` and the `.dll` the same name as the project. This can be changed in the project settings. I don't know whether the name of the `.lib` and the `.dll` can be changed independently, though -- but that will only lead to confusion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `.dll` is required to run. The `.lib` exists so the linker can resolve the ordinals and addresses from function names, and is only required at link time.

Other systems (such as Linux) maintain full linkage information in shared libraries and would not require this.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a DLL on Windows, you typically use it with a `.lib` file that tells the linker enough to be able to create an executable. The executable then uses the `.dll` file at run time.

OTOH, `dlopen` is a UNIX/Linux/POSIX kind of thing -- the equivalent on Windows would be `LoadLibrary`. You'd normally use `dlopen` with a `.so` file.